# Aggregate function by date

Tags: r

I have the head of my dataframe here 
data  tMax  tMin  tMed precipitacao

```
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
```

1 30/09/2016    29  17.8  23.4          0.0
2 29/09/2016    28  16.2  22.1          0.0
3 28/09/2016    24  17.2  20.6         11.4
4 27/09/2016    24  16.6  20.3         43.4
5 26/09/2016    26  17.2  21.6          0.0
6 25/09/2016    31  14.4  22.7          0.0

and I have this date format(xx/yy/zz). I'd like to aggregate my other variables(tMax,tMin,tMax and precipitacao) by year and by month.
Someone pls ;D

Answer (score 1):

First result on Google :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221425/how-do-i-group-my-date-variable-into-month-year-in-r

Basically:

1. Get dplyr
2. Add columns to your dataframe for year and month.
3. Group_by year and month and take averages.